# Do you need a commercial rating for aerial application work?

Tags: faa-regulations, aerial-application

So to be qualified to do [aerial application work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerial_application) do you have to have a private license with a commercial rating?

Comment: What is "arial application"?

Comment: Crop dusting. Spreading chemicals on fields by air

Answer (score 12):

Short answer: you can do aerial application on your own crops with a private certificate, but if you're going to do it commercially then you need a commercial certificate. In both cases you also need an agricultural aircraft operator certificate.

---

An agricultural aircraft operator certificate is required for aerial application, per [14 CFR 137.11](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=13b23e06fbbece9cc06a8eea5db8ac5b&mc=true&node=se14.3.137_111&rgn=div8). The airman certification requirements are in [137.19](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=13b23e06fbbece9cc06a8eea5db8ac5b&mc=true&node=se14.3.137_119&rgn=div8):

> (b) *Private operator—pilot*. The applicant must hold a current U.S.
>   private, commercial, or airline transport pilot certificate and be
>   properly rated for the aircraft to be used.
>
> (c) *Commercial operator—pilots*. The applicant must have available the
>   services of at least one person who holds a current U.S. commercial or
>   airline transport pilot certificate and who is properly rated for the
>   aircraft to be used.

The [FAA's AC 137](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC137-1A.pdf), *Certification Process for Agricultural Aircraft Operators* has all the details about how to get an operator's certificate and the airman requirements are in section 2-3. It says:

> Pilots designated to conduct operations for the commercial operator
>   applicant must hold a current commercial or airline transport pilot
>   certificate with the appropriate ratings

A private operator is limited to working his own crops:

> Private agricultural aircraft operators may not conduct operations for
>   compensation or hire, or conduct operations over a congested area. The
>   operator must provide proof of property ownership or other property
>   interest in the crop located on that property where the operation will
>   be conducted.

By the way, there's no such thing as a "commercial rating" in the US; private and commercial are both certificates.

Answer (score 3):

In the US, you are required to have a commercial license if you fly an aircraft "for compensation or hire". So yes a commercial license is required (in addition to lots of application specific training). I suppose you could dust your own crops without a commercial license depending on how the FAA determines how "compenstaion" applies in that case.

> **§61.133   Commercial pilot privileges and limitations.** (a) Privileges—(1) General. A person who holds a commercial pilot
>   certificate **may act as pilot in command** of an aircraft—
>
> (i) Carrying persons or property for compensation or hire, provided
>   the person is qualified in accordance with this part and with the
>   applicable parts of this chapter that apply to the operation; and
>
> (ii) For compensation or hire, provided the person is qualified in
>   accordance with this part and with the applicable parts of this
>   chapter that apply to the operation.

Comment: There's an ag school in Waco texas that offers chemical training as well as flight training for a tail dragger. They claim to have you "ready to be employed" when you graduate. So if I got my commercial license and did my schooling there I would essentially be ready to hire out to a ag application business or not?

Comment: @JackiKoehn That sounds like it would be a good start. I don’t know the  requirements of individual Ag Application companies so I can’t comment on whether you’d be ready to hire. They may have minimum total hours, tail-dragger hours, and age limits for insurance purposes. FYI to get your commercial license you need 250 hours of flight time.

Comment: I did 137 work some time ago, and the insurance company wanted me accident/incident free, with 2500 TT and 1500 in high performance aircraft.  They also wanted 25 hours in type, which was easy as I had flown a Pawnee towing gliders.  My boss had the biggest issue with finding pilots meeting the experience requirements and having a clean accident and enforcement record.  Go figure.