# What, as far as the FAA is concerned, is required for Ag Application?

Tags: faa-regulations, aerial-application

There are lots of "you need this..." comments, but I'm wondering what is required, legally, by the FAA?
A Commercial Rating, of course.  Flying for money and all.
A Taildragger Endorsement because the plane will probably be a TD.
A High Perf Endorsement because the plane will have over 300hp and very likely electric flaps - but maybe not cowl flaps.
But the FAA doesn't care about Insurance, does it? 
And really it doesn't care about the chemicals either, does it?  I mean in their statutes.
The Chems have state and fed guidelines, of course, but beyond the purview of the FAA.
Are there other ratings or certifications involved under the FAA?

Comment: From the context it is obvious you want to be a crop duster, but would you mind clarifying what you mean by "Ag Application"?  Is this something you apply to the FAA as a prerequisite for employment?  Because otherwise just what you listed ought to be all that is needed from their standpoint.  Of course your prospective employer would have to agree...

Comment: I'm told it's not called Crop Dusting anymore.

Comment: I already said I realize it requires a Commercial Ticket.      In fact, I said "Commercial Rating" of course"  So, no, it's not a dupe of that question which we already know.

Comment: Perhaps the other question isn't an exact dupe but the [currently accepted answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/44854/62) does point you to AC 137 in addition to answering the certification part. I don't know if you've already read that but it's probably what you're looking for. And as that answer mentions, a commercial certificate is *not* required for aerial application if it's on your own crops.

Comment: So if your answer is simply "go read 137" I can do that.  I was hoping someone would actually know the answer.  So far the first answer said "what you listed ought to be all that is needed" which I kind of opened with, but was hoping someone would actually know.

Comment: "I'm told it's not called Crop Dusting anymore."  I guess "aerial application" is more politically correct or somehow less offensive?!  Call it what you want, I call it crop dusting.